# get AD group path in the domain/tree

Tags: active-directory, powershell, ldap, windows-command-prompt

How to get the **path** of a specific group from the Domain/tree?
I am not getting to the info with the "Active Directory Users and Groups" program.

We have a extensive tree of folders beneath the company.com domain. And I want to know where a specific group "AXX G Doc Users" resides.
I'm experimenting with PowerShell Active Directory module, but no clue how to get the **path**.

```
PS C:\Users\hansi> get-adgroup "AXX G Doc Users"

DistinguishedName : CN=AXX G Doc Users,OU=Groups,OU=AXX,OU=AT,OU=Europe,OU=COMP Group,DC=comp,DC=com
GroupCategory     : Security
GroupScope        : Global
Name              : AXX G Doc Users
ObjectClass       : group
ObjectGUID        : 589de0db-105e-4cfe-a231-692573248487
SamAccountName    : AXX G Doc Users
SID               : S-1-5-21-796845957-79056718-725345543-16367
```

Comment: The path is right there in the output you posted. The DistinguishedName attribute is literally the LDAP path to the object in the domain.

Comment: you are right! even so, canonicalname makes me happy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2 ways so far:

- canonical name:

get-adgroup -identity "your group" -properties canonicalname | sel
-property canonicalname [enter]

canonicalname

Your.Domain/ou name/ou name/your group

- using the distinguishedname:

  $group = get-adgroup identity "your group" [enter]

  ($group.DistinguishedName -split"," ,2)[1] [enter]
  ou=name,ou,name,dc=your,dc=domain,dc=tld

sorry, I do not seem to get the right formatting, but you get the picture.

Comment: succeeded with: get-adgroup -identity "AXX G Doc Users" -properties canonicalname